# In Autofac, how can I get specific one instance when I call RegisterInstance with same type twice?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

```
builder
       .RegisterInstance(log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Logger"))
       .SingleInstance();

builder
       .RegisterInstance(log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("AsyncLogger"))
       .SingleInstance();
```

The above codes registered 2 logger instances from a same type. May I know how can I resolve specific one in runtime. e.g. by parameter?

Comment: You can use [named/keyed services](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html). Alternatively, you could create a factory that resolves the correct one and inject that instead.

Comment: Depending on what your ultimate goal is, [there are a few ways to deal with it](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html).